# Pycharm Edu IDE doesnt show plot when using Anaconda Python interpreter

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, anaconda

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
plt.plot(x, 'o')
plt.show()
```

The above code works in PyCharm if I choose the Python3.6 interpreter.

```
    3.6.1 (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6)
```

But if I change the interpreter to Anaconda Interpreter, I dont see any plots.

```
    3.6.3 (~/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python)
```

This is on a mac.

Comment: Do you have matplotlib installed in your anaconda virtual environment?

Comment: Yes. I have the same packages installed in the virtual env as in the standard Python installation ( plus a lot more).

Comment: Perhaps try it in the qtconsole.  It works much like a jupyter notebook but more concisely.  Last time I tried such plots worked there.  I haven't tried this from within pycharm though.  I would guess some incompatibility between pycharm and anaconda unless deeper tweaks are done.

Comment: I will try qtconsole. Thank you.